# Github multiple repositories defaulting to old username

Tags: git, github, ssh, public-key

I have all the settings configured in a way that appears correct, but git is still defaulting to an incorrect username.

I have the following set in git config:

```
alias.hist=log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:CORRECT_USER/project
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.email=ID+CORRECT_USER@users.noreply.github.com
user.name=CORRECT_USER
```

And it looks good.

My /.ssh/config also has:

```
Host github.com-CORRECT_USER
    HostName github.com
    User CORRECT_USER
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/CORRECT_USER_KEY
```

So it looks good, too.

However, when I...

```
git push
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Permission to  denied to TOTALLY_DIFFERENT_WRONG_USERNAME.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What is happening that git is trying to push the right repo, with the right username, and the right ssh/config using the TOTALLY_DIFFERENT_WRONG_USERNAME?  Where would that be set and how can I unset it?

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
$ ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

Will show which identity your ./ssh/config is actually connecting with in this repository.

In this case, it looks like it ran:

```
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
```

And went with your default username, which is TOTALLY_DIFFERENT_WRONG_USERNAME.

You can create different configs like so:

```
# user1
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User user1

# user2
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User user2
```

Comment: Turns out this actually doesn't work, so open to actual answers.